# null pointer exception when attempting to set a `CheckBox` to checked

Tags: android, checkbox

I am getting a null pointer exception when attempting to set a `CheckBox` to checked.

Example of my code:

```
CheckBox something;
something.setChecked(true);
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you know the difference between initializing and declaring a variable?

Comment: Well, you told the app "Hey, I want a `CheckBox` and I'm going to call it "something".  You then attempt to alter "something" without telling it which `CheckBox` "something" is!  Is it my `CheckBox`?  Your checkBox1, checkBox2, or checkBox3 defined in your XML?  A brand new `CheckBox`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you did not instantiate your `CheckBox` object properly.

If your `CheckBox` is in an xml file you can do :

```
something = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.idofYourCheckbox);
```

If not just do :

```
something = new CheckBox(Context ct);
```

[See this for more info.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html)

Answer (score 7):

That's because your something object is not initialized.

Initialize it with

```
CheckBox something = new CheckBox();
```

then use

```
something.setChecked(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Its because, You just **declared** `CheckBox something;` object, **not initialized it**.

Initialize it like,

```
CheckBox something = new CheckBox(this); // here 'this' is an activity context
```

Or,

```
something = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox); // This is from XML file
```